# Collapse cells in table using vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I try render schedule table using vue.js. In rows I have some activity (in this example only one hardcoded is present). In colls I have time periods. In cells - name of users, if user scheduled on this time.

[image]

You can see, that `Audrey` scheduled on 09:00 and on 09:30. My vue.js component code is here:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Object</th>
                <th :colspan="intervals.length">
                    Intervals
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="(interval, id) in intervals" :key="id">
                    {{interval.name}}
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Something</td>
                <td v-for="(interval, index) in intervals" :key="index">
                    {{getCell(interval.id).user_name}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Test',
        data () {
            return {
                intervals: [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "09:00:00",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "09:30:00",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "10:00:00",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "10:30:00",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "11:00:00",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "11:30:00",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "12:00:00",
                    },
                ],
                schedule: [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "interval_id": 1,
                        "user_name": "Audrey",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "interval_id": 2,
                        "user_name": "Audrey",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "interval_id": 4,
                        "user_name": "Ann",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "interval_id": 5,
                        "user_name": "Ann",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "interval_id": 7,
                        "user_name": "Chad",
                    },
                ],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getCell(interval_id) {
                return this.schedule.find(row => row.interval_id === interval_id) || {};
            },
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    table, table td, table th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }    
</style>
```

`Intervals` data and `Schedule` data come from API. But I want to collapse `Aundrey` cells to not display his (and `Ann's` too) `user_name` twice.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: This should to work for multiple use cases:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  filters: {
    /**
    * receives the first name of a group and if have prefix 'nobody' return ''
    */
    validateNames(name) {
      return name.split('_')[0] === 'nobody' ? '' : name
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      intervals: [
        {
          "id": 1, "name": "09:00:00",
        },
        {
          "id": 2, "name": "09:30:00",
        },
        {
          "id": 3, "name": "10:00:00",
        },
        {
          "id": 4, "name": "10:30:00",
        },
        {
          "id": 5, "name": "11:00:00",
        },
        {
          "id": 6, "name": "11:30:00",
        },
        {
          "id": 7, "name": "12:00:00",
        },
      ],
      scheduleOne: [
        {
          "id": 1, "interval_id": 1, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 2, "interval_id": 2, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 3, "interval_id": 4, "user_name": "Ann",
        },
        {
          "id": 4, "interval_id": 5, "user_name": "Ann",
        },
        {
          "id": 5, "interval_id": 7, "user_name": "Chad",
        }
      ],
      scheduleTwo: [
        {
          "id": 1, "interval_id": 1, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 2, "interval_id": 2, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 3, "interval_id": 3, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 4, "interval_id": 5, "user_name": "Ann",
        },
        {
          "id": 5, "interval_id": 7, "user_name": "Chad",
        }
      ],
      scheduleThree: [
        {
          "id": 1, "interval_id": 1, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 2, "interval_id": 2, "user_name": "Ann",
        },
        {
          "id": 3, "interval_id": 4, "user_name": "Ann",
        },
        {
          "id": 4, "interval_id": 6, "user_name": "Chad",
        },
        {
          "id": 5, "interval_id": 7, "user_name": "Chad",
        }
      ],
      scheduleFour: [
        {
          "id": 1, "interval_id": 1, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 2, "interval_id": 3, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 3, "interval_id": 5, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 4, "interval_id": 6, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 5, "interval_id": 7, "user_name": "Chad",
        }
      ],
      scheduleFive: [
        {
          "id": 1, "interval_id": 3, "user_name": "Chad",
        },
        {
          "id": 2, "interval_id": 4, "user_name": "Chad",
        },
        {
          "id": 3, "interval_id": 5, "user_name": "Chad",
        }
      ],
      scheduleSix: [
      ],
      scheduleSeven: [
        {
          "id": 1, "interval_id": 1, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 2, "interval_id": 2, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 3, "interval_id": 3, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 4, "interval_id": 4, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 5, "interval_id": 5, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 6, "interval_id": 6, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
        {
          "id": 7, "interval_id": 7, "user_name": "Audrey",
        },
      ]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    /**
    * assigning groups with same name for consecutives intervals
    * @param {Array<String>, Array<Array<String>>}
    */
    recursiveGroupsGenerator (intervalsNames, intervalsGroups) {
      // first name in intervalsNames[] && groupInterval[] to fill with consecutives names
      const currentUserName = intervalsNames[0], groupInterval = []

      // pushing only consecutives names in groupInterval[]
      for (const intervalName of intervalsNames) {
        if (currentUserName === intervalName) groupInterval.push(intervalName)
        else break;
      }
      // pushing in intervalsGroups[] the current groupInterval[]
      intervalsGroups.push(groupInterval)

      // splicing intervalsNames[] without the current groupInterval[]
      intervalsNames = intervalsNames.splice(groupInterval.length, intervalsNames.length - groupInterval.length)

      // calling to self as recursive while intervalsNames[] haves names
      // if intervalsNames[] is empty return intervalsGroups[]
      return intervalsNames.length > 0 ? this.recursiveGroupsGenerator(intervalsNames, intervalsGroups) : intervalsGroups          
    },

    resolveSchedule (schedule) {
      // getting array of names for each interval if not exists assign 'nobody_{index}'
      const assignedIntervalsNames = this.intervals.map((interval, index) => {
        const userAssigned = schedule.find(s => s.interval_id === interval.id)
        return userAssigned 
          ? userAssigned.user_name
          : `nobody_${index}`
      })
      // resolving groups with same name for consecutives intervals
      return this.recursiveGroupsGenerator(assignedIntervalsNames, [])
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table, table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr > td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Object</th>
        <th :colspan="intervals.length">
          Intervals
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="(interval, id) in intervals" :key="id">
          {{interval.name}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>scheduleOne</td>
        <td v-for="(item, index) in resolveSchedule(scheduleOne)" :key="index" :colspan="item.length">
          {{ item[0] | validateNames }}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>scheduleTwo</td>
        <td v-for="(item, index) in resolveSchedule(scheduleTwo)" :key="index" :colspan="item.length">
          {{ item[0] | validateNames }}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>scheduleThree</td>
        <td v-for="(item, index) in resolveSchedule(scheduleThree)" :key="index" :colspan="item.length">
          {{ item[0] | validateNames }}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>scheduleFour</td>
        <td v-for="(item, index) in resolveSchedule(scheduleFour)" :key="index" :colspan="item.length">
          {{ item[0] | validateNames }}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>scheduleFive</td>
        <td v-for="(item, index) in resolveSchedule(scheduleFive)" :key="index" :colspan="item.length">
          {{ item[0] | validateNames }}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>scheduleSix</td>
        <td v-for="(item, index) in resolveSchedule(scheduleSix)" :key="index" :colspan="item.length">
          {{ item[0] | validateNames }}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>scheduleSeven</td>
        <td v-for="(item, index) in resolveSchedule(scheduleSeven)" :key="index" :colspan="item.length">
          {{ item[0] | validateNames }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: if in schedule no records or if present only Chad's or Ann's recors, it looks strange. It collapse all empty cells - https://i.ibb.co/gZhfPLR/2020-01-12-134849.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've done away with the `getCell` method and created a `scheduleSpans` computed instead.  It returns an array of array/pairs, the first entry being the name, the second entry being the colspan.  Then I use this in the v-for where you'd been calling the now unnecessary `getCell`.

I don't want to repeat all your other code, first here is the new v-for loop instead of calling `getCell`:

```
<tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td v-for="(span, index) in scheduleSpans" :key="index" :colspan="span[1]">
        {{span[0]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

And here is the `scheduleSpans` computed; again, you should now be able to delete `getCells`:

```
computed: {
    scheduleSpans() {
        return this.intervals.reduce((scheduleSpans, interval) => {
            const scheduleEntry = 
                this.schedule.find(entry => entry.interval_id === interval.id);
            const userName = scheduleEntry ? scheduleEntry.user_name : '';

            if (scheduleSpans.length === 0) scheduleSpans[0] = [userName, 0];
            if (scheduleSpans[scheduleSpans.length - 1][0] !== userName) {
                scheduleSpans[scheduleSpans.length] = [userName, 0];
            }
            scheduleSpans[scheduleSpans.length - 1][1] = 
                scheduleSpans[scheduleSpans.length - 1][1] + 1;

            return scheduleSpans;
        }, []);
    }
},
/*
methods: {
    getCell(interval_id) {
        return this.schedule.find(row => row.interval_id === interval_id) || {};
    },
}
*/
```

The data from `scheduleSpans` is as follows:

```
[["Audrey",2],["",1],["Ann",2],["",1],["Chad",1]]
```

Because I used an array of array/pairs, rather than a map which might have started by returning `{"Audrey": 2}` etc., the same names can appear again later in the schedule data and it will still work.

This is the resulting table: [image]

EDIT:
Code has been modified so that empty user names always get their own column.  Renamed `scheduleSpans` computed to `schedulePairs`, and cleaned up and commented the code.  Now the table row is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td v-for="(span, index) in schedulePairs" :key="index" :colspan="span[1]">
        {{span[0]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

And to test that non-existent user schedule entries always had their own span I deleted one of the blocks for Ann, using the following mocked `schedule` data:

```
schedule: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "interval_id": 1,
        "user_name": "Audrey",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "interval_id": 2,
        "user_name": "Audrey",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "interval_id": 4,
        "user_name": "Ann",
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "interval_id": 7,
        "user_name": "Chad",
    },
]
```

Finally, the `schedulePairs` computed:

```
computed: {
    schedulePairs() {
        // Returns a data structure, specifically an array of arrays with two values ("pairs")
        // Each pair containing the user name and the number of columns that value should span
        return this.intervals.reduce((pairs, interval) => {
            const scheduleEntry = this.schedule.find(entry => 
                entry.interval_id === interval.id
            );
            const userName = scheduleEntry ? scheduleEntry.user_name : '';

            // Push new pair with colspan of zero (incremented below if's) on first iteration
            if (pairs.length === 0) pairs.push([userName, 0]);

            // Also push new pair is userName is empty or isn't the same as for last pair
            if (userName === '' || lastPair()[0] !== userName) pairs.push([userName, 0]);

            lastPair()[1] = lastPair()[1] + 1;
            return pairs;

            // Cleaner than repeating  pairs[pairs.length - 1]
            function lastPair() { return pairs[pairs.length - 1] }
        }, []);
    }
}
```

Comment: if in `schedule` no records or if present only Chad's or Ann's recors, it looks strange. It collapse all empty cells

Answer (score -1):

try to do something like this

After fetching the API inside your table. You can perform some JS code to remove duplicated cells in a row

```html
<table>
     <tbody>
     <tr class="this-test">
         <td>is</td>
         <td>is</td>
         <td>is</td>        
     </tr>
     <tr class="this-test">
         <td>this</td>
         <td>is</td>
         <td>something</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="this-test">
         <td>this</td>
         <td>is</td>
         <td>something</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
<script>
    var test = document.getElementsByClassName('this-test');
    for(var i =0; i< test[1].cells.length -2; i++){
        if(test[0].cells[i].innerText == test[0].cells[i+1].innerText){
           test[0].cells[i].colSpan++;
           test[0].deleteCell(i+1);
           i--;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't even remotely related to the data returned by the API

Comment: perform the code after fetching the AP
just add the class "this-test" to the rows that you need to remove duplicated cells from